# time.sleep in python does not work but exits immediately

Tags: python

I am using below code in Nifi in executeScript and have added time.sleep to add delay in the code so that it tries after some time but this does not work as expected. It prints the logs one after the other without waiting

```
 class ModJSON(StreamCallback):
        def __init__(self):
            pass

        def process(self, inputStream, outputStream):
            text = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
            obj = json.loads(text)
            response = self._updateelasticsearch(timestamp, flowID, elasticSearchURL, indexName)
            log.error("response : " + response)
            flowcounter = 1

            while (response.find('"updated":1') == -1 & flowcounter < 35):
                flowcounter += 1
                time.sleep(50)
                response = self._updateelasticsearch(timestamp, flowID, elasticSearchURL, indexName)

            flowcounter = 0
            outputStream.write(bytearray(json.dumps(response, indent=4).encode('utf-8')))

        def _updateelasticsearch(self, timestamp, flowID, elasticSearchURL, indexName):
            try:
                #update code
            return rest_response

        def _validateIfExist(self, flowid, elasticSearchURL, indexName) :
            #validatecode

            if record_count > 0:
                return True
            else :
                return False


    flowFile = session.get()
    if (flowFile != None):
        flowFile = session.write(flowFile, ModJSON())
        session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
        session.commit()
```

Comment: Perhaps the while loop is never being entered?

Comment: Did you misspell `and` in the `while` condition?

Comment: replace `&` by `and`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your `while` loop is never being entered.

```
while (response.find('"updated":1') == -1 & flowcounter < 35):
                                          ^ problem
```

The bitwise `&` operator behaves differently than the boolean `and` operator. `&` has different precedence than `and`, so it can give surprising results:

```
>>> 1 == 1 & 2 == 2
False
```

Similarly, your expression `response.find('"updated":1') == -1 & flowcounter < 35` only evaluates to True when `response.find('"updated":1') == (-1 & flowcounter)` and when `(-1 & flowcounter) < 35`. `(-1 & flowcounter)` is never equal to -1 when `flowcounter` is positive, so your conditional will never succeed when `response.find('"updated":1')` returns -1.

If you're only trying to logically chain together clauses in a conditional, use `and`.

```
while (response.find('"updated":1') == -1 and flowcounter < 35):
```